# How to creat a pdf on client side and open it in new browser tap AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am required to create pdf file on client side using AngularJS and download it in new tab on browser, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pdfMake](http://pdfmake.org/#/) to generate PDF on the front end. It uses pure JS to generate PDFs

Answer (score 0):

Use the PDF lib from mozilla to create PDF files using JavaScript, can be used with AngularJS ofcourse:

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/